# Eclipse internal compiler error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

When using this code in Eclipse:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> objs = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object());
        Set<String> s = objs.stream().collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add, Object::toString);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at 
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ConstraintExpressionFormula.reduceReferenceExpressionCompatibility(ConstraintExpressionFormula
 .java:273)
```

I know that this is this line which is producing the error:

```
Set<String> s = objs.stream().collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add, Object::toString);
```

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm using:

- Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2
- Plugins: Eclipse Java Development Tools Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2) and Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment Patch with Java 8 support (for Kepler SR2)
- java.runtime.version=1.8.0-b132

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I know that the collect method is not correct but why I don't have a compiler error telling something like:

```
- The method collect(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R,? super Object>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type Stream<Object> is not applicable for the arguments etc.
```

Comment: Well presumably this is just an Eclipse bug. I think you'd be better off filing a bug with the Eclipse project than asking the question here.

Comment: I would check if this works `List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object()));` because Arrays.asList creates an immutable List.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Same problem :(. Why creating a non-fixed size list would change this?

Comment: @user2336315 Clearly it didn't matter. It was a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [433085](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433085) a duplicate of bug [430766](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430766). This is targeted to be fixed in Eclipse 4.4 Luna M7.

Comment: I see. Thanks there was another bug listed which were troubling me too. Waiting for the correction then!